# What will be the time complexity of this brute force apporach of finding largest valid bst in a binary tree?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

```
    
int size(Node* root){
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return 0;
    }
    return size(root->left) + 1 + size(root->right);
}
bool isBST(Node* node, int min, int max)
{
    if (node == nullptr) {
        return true;
    }
    if (node->data < min || node->data > max) {
        return false;
    }
    return isBST(node->left, min, node->data) &&
        isBST(node->right, node->data, max);
}
int findLargestBST(Node* root)
{
    if (isBST(root, INT_MIN, INT_MAX)) {
        return size(root);
    }
 
    return max(findLargestBST(root->left), findLargestBST(root->right));
}
```

This is a code to find largest bst in a binary tree.
So according to [this](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-size-largest-bst-in-binary-tree/) post the worst case time complexity of brute force solution is O(n^2) but how? It should be O(n^3) no ? since we are passing size function also

Comment: `This is a code to find largest bst in a binary tree.` No, it isn't. Any BST that cotains `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX` will not be found.

Comment: welp let's just say values are less than that always :p

Comment: what about trees with duplicate values?

Comment: yeah i forgot to put here <= and >= but in the other portal (gfg) i used it, i think for this specific code they are assuming it to not have duplicate elems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size function is only ever used once and is `O(n)`. So the complexity is `O(n^2 + n) == O(n^2)`.

Update: Let me rephrase this as my reasoning wasn't clear at all.

The `size` function gets called many times. Either because a tree is BST or somewhere down there for each subtree when `findLargestBST` is called with each subtree. The `size` function also gets called recursively by `size` itself.

But for each node `size` is called at most once. So accumulated it is `O(n)`. To see this you have to look at the two cases in `findLargestBST`.

If the tree is BST then `size` gets called for the whole tree and internally recurses to each element of the tree.

If the tree is not BST then the tree is split and `size` can be called for each subtree. But at most that looks at each element in the left tree and each element in the right tree. The two (or more) calls to `size` can never overlap and look at an element more than once.

Accumulated that is `O(n)`.

Comment: if there are multiple bst's then the size func will be called multiple times right?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it's called for each subtree.

Comment: so confusing as to why they put it to O(n^2)